# 'Datetime' value showing up as 2014-11-02T05:00:00.000Z instead of 2014-11-02 00:00:00

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, phpmyadmin

Edit: SELECT * query is returning my dates in an incorrect format. Using the mysql2 module to execute a connection.query(), pass all data to a server-side variable, and calling it client-side using AJAX.

```js
router.post('/applicants', function(req, res){
 connectionpool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
        if(err){
            console.error('CONNECTION error: ', err);
            res.statusCode = 503;
            res.send({
                result: 'error',
                err: err.code
            });
        } else {
            console.log
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM applicant',
                function(err, rows){
                    if (err) console.error(err);
                    res.send(rows);
                }
            );
            connection.release();
        }
    });
});
```

```js
 var applicants = ''; 
 $.post('/applicants').done(function(data){
  applicants = data;
 });
```

```js
 $('.name').click(function(){
  var selected = $(this).attr('id');
  applicants.forEach(function(applicant){
   if(selected == applicant.applicant_id){
              
              ...
              $('input[name="applicant_dob"]').val(applicant.applicant_dob);
```

I can't parse it out by '-' because it returns the day as 02T05:00:00.000Z instead of 02. It looks correct in phpmyadmin. Any ideas?

Comment: @BastienSander that's a poor attitude to have towards a new account. You didn't even ask what the code for what they tried is, or offer a link to help learn. Don't be that guy

Comment: @BastienSander not sure what happened, but I have to confess I was a little aware that this wasn't good form for a post. I'm in a hurry and was looking for a quick response. It seems like something specific to mysql so I didn't think any code would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking at at a field with type ["datetime with timezone"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)

you could modify the output in your query using the [date_format()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function of mysql.

Comment: what about changing the datatype for the whole column? I'm using dummy data right now so it won't hurt anything. first data type i tried was DATE, as I don't need time. It returned what I posted. Then I tried DATETIME just to see what would happen. Same thing. PHPMyAdmin always looks right, but calling it the way I am is resulting in the timezone being added